# Angularjs directive d3 pie chart wrong centering

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have a pie chart directive that uses d3 to create a pie chart. However, it centers in the wrong place, so only the bottom right of the chart is showing on the screen. 
I have tried using existing chart directives (such as angular-nvd3) but I couldn't get them working with requirejs (I posted a question about that but got no answers).

I am now close to getting this one working, but the positioning is off. I tried searching the d3 api for help on positioning but didn't find anything that helped at all.

Here is my code for the pie chart directive:

```
 .directive('d3Pie', ['d3',
        function (d3) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    data: "=",
                    label: "@",
                    onClick: "&"
                },
                link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    var svg = d3.select(iElement[0])
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", "100%"),
                        color = d3.scale.category20();


                    // on window resize, re-render d3 canvas
                    window.onresize = function () {
                        return scope.$apply();
                    };
                    scope.$watch(function () {
                        return angular.element(window)[0].innerWidth;
                    }, function () {
                        return scope.render(scope.data);
                    });

                    // watch for data changes and re-render
                    scope.$watch('data', function (newVals, oldVals) {
                        return scope.render(newVals);
                    }, true);

                     // define render function
                    scope.render = function (data) {
                         // remove all previous items before render
                        svg.selectAll("*").remove();
                        var width, height, radius;
                        width = d3.select(iElement[0])[0][0].offsetWidth;
                        height = 500;
                        radius = width/2;



                        svg.attr('height', height);

                        svg             //create the SVG element inside the iElement
                        .data([data])   
                        .attr("width", width)//set width and height
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold pie chart
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")//move center of pie chart


                        var arc = d3.svg.arc()  
                        .outerRadius(radius);

                        var pie = d3.layout.pie()//create arc data  given a list of values
                                    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });


                        var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.slice") //selects all elements with class slice
                                .data(pie)  //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
                                .enter()   // creating a <g> for every object in the data array
                                .append("svg:g")  //create a group to hold each slice
                                .on("click", function (item) {
                                        console.log("hello",item);
                                })
                                .attr("class", "slice"); 

                    arcs.append("svg:path")
                        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) //set the color 
                        .attr("d", arc);//this creates the actual SVG path  
                    }

                }
            }



        }]);
```

I tried playing with this line :

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")//move center of pie chart
```

but it didnt seem to affect the positioning at all.